# XML schema how to specify a list of options of which AT LEAST one must occur?

Tags: xsd

I am trying to specify a list of options (i.e. a sequence of elements) of which at least one must occur. (but not necessarily more than one).

A method which kinda works but is clearly the wrong way to do it is this:

```
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:choice>
    <xs:element name="apple" type="xsd:string" />
    <xs:element name="banana" type="xsd:string" />
    <xs:element name="pear" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

This kind of works, however you could specify multiple of any item (e.g. 2 bananas) and also sequencing is lost (banana could come before apple).

There must be a better way of doing this!? but I have searched for a few hours and not found one.

Does anyone know how this should be done?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your original question only refers to Schema, and makes no mention of Java or any other application logic. Yet you have stated that the other Schema only solutions provided by @Dan and @jasso are insufficient, due to your application requirements.

Since you have an application to leverage, document it in schema, then apply your logic in the application code.

Schema:

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
        At least one of apple, banana, or pear is required.
    </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="apple" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="banana" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="pear" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Java:

```
if (apple == null && banana == null && pear == null)
{
  throw new IllegalStateException("At least one of apple, banana or pear is required.");
}
```

If your application will allow you to do multi-staged parsing, then you could look into formalizing the assertion documentation into something more formalized.

[Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) is well suited for this purpose.

It allows you to specify assertion rules as XPath expressions. You can then compile these assertions into XSLT transforms, which you can apply in your xml transformation pipeline to do additional validations.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I can't use schematron, so I guess java validation is the way to go! I just thought it was possible to specify all the validation in the schema so it wouldn't be necessary in Java, but I suppose this particular thing should be validated with Java code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the order is significant (a banana cannot appear before apple and pear must appear last), only one occurrence of each fruit is permitted, but there must be at least one fruit.

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

The result looks a bit complicated, but it doesn't require iterating through all combinations.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do it without using choice? I am generating java classes from the xml schema, and it doesn't work well with choice. Without choice it generates get/set functions e.g. getApple, getBanana. but with choice it generates methods like getAppleOrBanana. Is there a way to do it without choice? Also, with more than three options, the schema is going to get very long and repetitive doing it this way!

Comment: @Jimmy: Well you could try to fool the class generator by wrapping the choice into sequence or by referring to global elements instead of defining them locally. Otherwise it's better to follow @Dan's newer answer or to loosen your restrictions for example by making all elements mandatory (in a sequence) but allow them to be empty (which xs:string already does, if that is the final type). After all, you try to get the elements independently, yet they are interdependent because their position and cardinality depends on the presence of other fruit elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="pear" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do it without using choice? I am generating java classes from the xml schema, and it doesn't work well with choice. Without choice it generates get/set functions e.g. getApple, getBanana. but with choice it generates methods like getAppleOrBanana. Is there a way to do it without choice? Also, with more than three options, the schema is going to get very long and repetitive doing it this way!

Comment: i actually want to do it with 7 elements so this way would require a few hundred choices!